# Show basic auth popup if user is not logged in

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I have several files that can be downloaded on my website. 
The HTML content refers to this method:

```
from flask_httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth
auth = HTTPBasicAuth()
...
@app.route('/customer_section/download/<product_id>')
@login_required
def customer_download_file(product_id):
    # get the company the currently logged in user belongs to
    user_company = current_user.company

    # get the product entity
    product = Product.query.filter_by(id=product_id).first_or_404()

    # now get the company, the product belongs to
    product_company = product.project.owner

    if current_user.is_admin or (not current_user.is_admin and product_company.id == user_company.id):

        print("Splitting Path %s to folder and filename..." % product.path)

        # Split the path to folder and filename
        folder, filename = os.path.split(product.path)

        return send_from_directory(folder, filename, mimetype="application/octet-stream", as_attachment=True)
    else:
        # Unauthorized
        abort(401)
```

This works great when the user logs in via flask_login in my login view. 
So the user logs in via my login view, then somehow navigates through my website, and the clicks on a download link to download a file.

But what if a user tries to download a file directly? 
I'd then like to show the user a popup so the user can enter his credentials and may download the file.

Is this possible?

Sorry, I guess my description was not clear enough: I‘m not trying to show a custom popup view of mine when a user calls my download method. I‘d like the default (browser specific) Basic Authentication popup to appear if a non logged in user tries to call that specific url. As if I had a restrictive .htaccess file that ensures that only authorized users continue. If the user reaches the same url via my webpage (after logging in, this method simply returns the file stream).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after reading this [link](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/8/) I solved it like this:

```
def get_db_user(username):
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
    return user


def check_auth(username, password):
    """This function is called to check if a username /
    password combination is valid.
    """

    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return True

    user = get_db_user(username)
    if not user or not user.check_password(password):
        return False
    else:
        return True


@login.unauthorized_handler
def handle_unauthorized_callback():

    page_to_load = request.path
    print("Tried to access page: %s" % page_to_load)
    # this regex match checks whether a specific url was called
    if is_file_download_url_pattern.match(page_to_load):
        basic_auth = request.authorization
        if not basic_auth or not check_auth(basic_auth.username, basic_auth.password):
            return authenticate()
        else:
            user = get_db_user(basic_auth.username)
            login_user(user, False)

            # extract product id
            product_id = re.search(product_id_pattern, page_to_load).group()

            return customer_download_file(int(product_id))

    else:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))


def authenticate():
    """Sends a 401 response that enables basic auth"""
    return Response(
        'Could not verify your access level for that URL.\n'
        'You have to login with proper credentials', 401,
        {'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="Login Required"'}
    )
```

I don't know whether this is an elegant solution, but at least it solves my problem for now. 
Thanks.